# javascript project facet name?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Would somebody let me know what is the name of JavaScript facet (not nature) in Eclipse? I found name of "Dynamic Web Module" facet i.e, "jst.web" but could not find for JavaScript. I have to add it as required facets in my facet.
Here is relevant fragment of my plugin.xml:

```
<project-facet-version facet="mytool" version="1.0">
    <constraint>
        <requires facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/> <!-- Dynamic Web Module -->
        <requires facet="???????" version="1.0"/> <!-- JavaScript Project -->
    </constraint>
    <action type="INSTALL" id="mytool.install">
        <config-factory class="mytool.MyFacetInstallConfig$Factory"/>
        <delegate class="mytool.MyFacetInstallDelegate"/>
    </action>
</project-facet-version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It's `wst.jsdt.web`.
Thank you everybody who has spent time to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the JavaScript nature?  That's "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature".

To add a given nature, you need the `IProject` for a given projject, and then get its `IProjectDescription`.  Create a `String` array with all the existing natures plus your new one[s], and set that back into the project description.  Finally, set the description back into the project (which triggers an update IIRC, even though you're using the exact same object).

Comment: Thank you @Mark for your answer but probably I could not explain my question well (that I tried in current edit, please have a look). I want to write a facet to customize New Project wizard according to my  needsThank you @Mark for your answer but probably I could not explain my question well (that I tried in current edit). I want to write a facet to customize New Project wizard according to my own requirements. It will not change or add project nature that are coming from underlying required facets